# Knex.js multiple orderBy() columns

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Is it possible to do multiple orderBy() columns?

```
knex
  .select()
  .table('products')
  .orderBy('id', 'asc')
```

The orderBy() chainable only takes a single column key and a sort value, but how can I order by multiple columns?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a special function for that, but you can do a `orderByRaw` and write whatever you need

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that, but it's my last resort.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can [call `.orderBy` multiple times](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/34d9a7650ea9170c241ab026bd601e24e7d76fb9/test/unit/query/builder.js#L1107:L1122) to order by multiple columns:

```
knex
  .select()
  .table('products')
  .orderBy('name', 'desc')
  .orderBy('id', 'asc')
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to apply that programatically? for an unknown number of orderBy fields?

Comment: Just iterate over the list of columns and call `orderBy` for each. I'll save the basic JS as an exercise for you :)

Answer (score 21):

The original answer is technically correct, and useful, but my intention was to find a way to programatically apply the `orderBy()` function multiple times, here is the actual solution I went with for reference:

```
var sortArray = [
  {'field': 'title', 'direction': 'asc'}, 
  {'field': 'id', 'direction': 'desc'}
];

knex
  .select()
  .table('products')
  .modify(function(queryBuilder) {
    _.each(sortArray, function(sort) {
      queryBuilder.orderBy(sort.field, sort.direction);
    });
  })
```

Knex offers a modify function which allows the queryBuilder to be operated on directly. An array iterator then calls `orderBy()` multiple times.

Comment: I think the original answer was working as you intended too. For instance:

    let query = knex
      .select()
      .table('products');

    _.each(sortArray, function(sort) {
      query.orderBy(sort.field, sort.direction);
    });

Answer (score 21):

The Knex orderBy function also receives an array:

```
knex('users').orderBy(['email', 'age', 'name'])
```

or

```
knex('users').orderBy(['email', { column: 'age', order: 'desc' }])
```

or

```
knex('users').orderBy([{ column: 'email' }, { column: 'age', order: 'desc' }])
```

Comment: This is more elegant way of doing it than marked answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
const builder = knex.table('products');

sortArray.forEach(
  ({ field, direction }) => builder.orderBy(field, direction)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`orderBy` accepts an array of type:

```js
[
  {column: 'id', order: 'asc'},
  {column: 'name', order: 'desc'},
  {column: 'created_at', order: 'desc'},
]
```

i have a function that takes a param from the request:

```js
sort=id,name,-created_at
```

and builds an array that is passed to the `queryBuilder`

`columns` is an array with the accepted values of table columns

```js
sort(model, sorts, columns) {

    let confirmed = true;

    sorts = sorts.split(',')
    sorts.forEach((sort: string) => {
        sort      = sort.replace('-', '')
        sort      = sort.replace(' ', '')
        confirmed = columns.includes(sort)
        if (!confirmed) {
            let index = sorts.indexOf(sort)
            sorts.splice(index, 1)
        }
    })

    let sortsArr = [];

    sorts.forEach((sort) => {
        if (sort.startsWith('-')) {
            sort = sort.replace('-', '')
            sortsArr.push({column: model.tableName + '.' + sort, order: 'desc'})
        } else {
            sortsArr.push({column: model.tableName + '.' + sort, order: 'asc'})
        }
    })
    return sortsArr;
}
```

and then use it like this in the query

```js
const sortsArr = sort(model, sorts, model.columns);

knex('users').orderBy(sortsArr)
```